# Probelm with Spyder 4.01 and Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pyspider

Spyder (4.1) does not work anymore with python 2.7 in Anaconda environnement.
When I launch spyder it does not open and I do not have any message.

If I launch spyder with python 3.8 it works.

conda environment :
[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 has officially been retired as one can see in [`PEP 373`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/), but if it is necessary to use python 2 you could try using an older version of the spyder package. If you wish to use your code in the long-term it is highly advised to migrate necessary to python 3. I hope this helped